# Can't manage to insert the correct path for a .mp3 in an cordova project

Tags: android, angular, cordova, path, media

I've created a project with angular 7, and it works fine.

So I've tried to wrap the project with Apache Cordova.

I've add the *browser* platform, and all works fine... But when I add the *android* platform, the sound files (that was both played in angular and cordova browser) weren't load...

The path isn't valid... i've tried a lot of path (relative and absolute path) but none seems to work...

[image: info]

(if you need a more focused image)
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Z5G_0VBcbRzWQF3ySwllx7xSAiXqMd9a/view?usp=sharing

what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You will need to append `cordova.file.applicationDirectory` before your path string. This will point to your `www` folder, and from there you can point to the actual file.